TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'toBase58')
Hello Im trying to get the metadata for the latest 5 newly minted tokens on the blockchain, I keep getting the error
const args = this._buildArgsAtLeastConfirmed([address.toBase58()], commitment, undefined, options);
                                                      ^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'toBase58')
at Connection.getSignaturesForAddress (C:\Users\user\node_modules@solana\web3.js\lib\index.cjs.js:7691:59)
at main (C:\Users\user\OneDrive\Desktop\Solana\solana.js:20:45)
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
Here is my code
const { Connection, clusterApiUrl, PublicKey } = require('@solana/web3.js');
const { TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID, Token } = require("@solana/spl-token");

async function fetchTokenMetadata(connection, tokenMintAddress) {
  const token = new Token(connection, tokenMintAddress, TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID, null);
  const tokenInfo = await token.getMintInfo();
  return tokenInfo;
}

async function main() {
  const connection = new Connection(clusterApiUrl('mainnet-beta'), 'confirmed');

  // Fetch the latest blockhash
  const latestBlockhash = await connection.getLatestBlockhash();

  // Fetch the latest slot
  const latestSlot = latestBlockhash.blockhash.slot;

  // Fetch the most recent signatures
  const recentSignatures = await connection.getSignaturesForAddress(
    connection.publicKey,
    { limit: 100, before: null },
    'confirmed'
  );

  const filteredSignatures = recentSignatures.filter(signature => signature.slot <= latestSlot);

  // Extract token accounts from signatures
  const tokenAccountAddresses = filteredSignatures
    .flatMap(signature => {
      const transaction = connection.current.rpc.getTransaction(signature.signature, 'confirmed');
      return transaction.transaction.message.instructions
        .filter(instruction => instruction.programId.equals(TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID))
        .flatMap(instruction => instruction.accounts
          .filter(account => account.isSigner || account.isWritable)
          .map(account => account.toString())
        );
    })
    .slice(0, 5); // Limits to the 5 latest token accounts can change later

  const promises = tokenAccountAddresses.map(async (mintAddress) => {
    return fetchTokenMetadata(connection, new PublicKey(mintAddress));
  });

  const tokenInfos = await Promise.all(promises);

  tokenInfos.forEach((tokenInfo, index) => {
    console.log(`Token Metadata for ${tokenAccountAddresses[index]}:`);
    console.log(tokenInfo);
  });
}

main();


I would appreciate if anyone could help me with this as its been really hard so far to learn and use solanas tools.
Thanks!

The Connection object doesn't have a publicKey field, which is why you're getting an undefined address. You can see all its fields/methods here: https://solana-labs.github.io/solana-web3.js/classes/Connection.html
I'm not sure which address you're expecting that to be. But you probably want something like this:
// use your address
const myPublicKey = new PublicKey('B556Hnif217eTSdyTFkwvVXAWftfDXFkxrAeKGfpHEQ');

const recentSignatures = await connection.getSignaturesForAddress(
    myPublicKey,
    { limit: 100, before: null },
    'confirmed'
);


Honestly these docs dont make any sense to me they are so confusing idk what to do

What address are you trying to get transactions for? And which doc did you get connection.publicKey from, we shouldn't have that documented anywhere because it doesn't exist so I think wherever you got that is likely the source of confusion here.

I found  it in the libraries source code, in this code I was trying to get the transactions related to the mainnet by using its public key

The objective was for me to get metadata for all newly minted tokens, the 5 latest ones at least
